# Render icons from an SVG file on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg

I have an `icons.svg` file that seems to contain assets that I need to use in my Angular app.

The file looks something like this (note, the `...` means omitted data due to security reasons):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs>
<path d="..." id="o"/></defs>
<symbol id="icon-add-member-contain-heavy" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
<path d="B0 ... 4A3q"/>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-add-member-contain-light" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
<path d="A5 ... 2i5m"

...
...
.../></symbol></svg>
```

I am trying to reference the file in my component HTML (as shown in the code below), but I don't know how to render an icon. I am guessing I need to use the `id`'s that are shown in the above svg code, like `id="icon-add-member-contain-heavy"`?

```
    <div>
      <img src="../../src/assets/icons.svg">
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have only symbols? Are you allowed to change the code? Please read about [How SVG Fragment Identifiers Work](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/)

Answer (score 0):

In angular, you should be able to render the svg as a component. From the angular docs:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-svg',
  templateUrl: './svg.component.svg',
  styleUrls: ['./svg.component.css']
})
export class SvgComponent {
  fillColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';

  changeColor() {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    this.fillColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
  }
}
```